# I got this error while using wxPython on windows " import wx import error no module named wx "

Tags: python, import, wxwidgets

I'm new to wxPython. I just installed Python 2.7.9 and wxPython for 2.7 on my Windows 7.
When I try to run the "helloworld" file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wx

app = wx.App(False)  # Create a new app, don't redirect stdout/stderr to a window.
frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Hello World") # A Frame is a top-level window.
frame.Show(True)     # Show the frame.
app.MainLoop()
```

from the official website.I got this error

```
c:\Workspace>python hellowword.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hellowword.py", line 2, in <module>
    import wx
ImportError: No module named wx
```

I've looked through other posts on stacksoverflow, e.g.[Wx not importing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056843/wx-not-importing)
[Can't load packages due to 'No module named wx' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100007/cant-load-packages-due-to-no-module-named-wx-error)

But none of them worked.

I've already added directory of wxPython to path "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages". Still failed.

Could anyone help me with this, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what the the installation enviornment i.e. OS, python version and the wx version you trying to install ?

Comment: http://wxpython.org/BUILD-2.8.html I had to follow step by step installation guide at this page to make it work

Comment: Thanks a lot for prompt response. I already fixed this by reinstalling python and wxPython, following this instruction step by step. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NMjV_HGLAQE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already fixed this by reinstalling python and wxPython, following this instruction step by step. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NMjV_HGLAQE