# import error in wxPython: import wx.animate on windows7(64bit OS) with python3.5.1 in Anaconda 4.2.0(32bit)

Tags: windows, user-interface, wxpython, anaconda, python-3.5

I am working on Windows7(64 bit OS) with Anaconda's python 3.5.1(32bit).
I have installed wxPython for GUI.
I keep getting the below import error
`ImportError: No module named 'wx.animate'`

`import wx` is working fine.
`import wx`
`wx.version()`

gives

`'3.0.3.dev2752+8304ec1 msw (phoenix)''`

I have installed wxPython from
https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/

the version is,
**wxPython_Phoenix-3.0.3.dev2752+8304ec1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl**

I have checked the path and don't see any problem there..
Can anyone guide me on where this is going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Try this solution from stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29634555/6918812

Comment: @ShubhamNamdeo  ok, I will try that. looks like 32bit python is a problem..thnks

Answer (score 1):

The classes formerly in `wx.animate` in wxPython Classic are now in `wx.adv` in wxPython Phoenix. See https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/classic_vs_phoenix.html#modules-which-have-moved